# Is it possible to find, compare and modify the fields in several rows using a single query?

Tags: mongodb, mongotemplate

I am using MongoTemplate to accomplish my task with 2 queries. But wanted to know if it's possible to do the same with a single query.
Example-

1. Filter the records based on a boolean value **(isSaved)**,
2. In each record pick the **field(boughtDate)** and check if it was bought yesterday.
3. If yes, then update the **field(isPromoValid)** to **true**.

What I do now is. I just query to get the records based on a filter condition. Locally do date comparison on each record's Date field. Then use updateMany to update all the records

Comment: Why can't you use a single `update` query?

Comment: Please share sample data and your queries

Comment: Does a single update query do all these 3? I am from a mobile app back ground. New to backend programming and MongoDB. Would be helpful if you could share the query for this, please.

Comment: I just query to get the records based on a filter condition. Locally do date comparison on each record's Date field. Then use updateMany to update all the records.

Comment: You can run one update query that checks both the boolean and the date and update the field for matching documents. If you provide the sample data I can show you. The lack of the sample data and your queries, is probably the reason that this question was down-voted.

Comment: Lack of sample data makes this a guess, but does this [mongoplayground.net example](https://mongoplayground.net/p/QEyV39bflTi "link to mongoplayground -->") help?

Comment: Thanks @nimrodserok  Based on your suggestion. I have found how to do this. Thank you so much for your time.

Answer (score 0):

```
BulkOperations bulkOps = template.bulkOps(BulkOperations.BulkMode.UNORDERED, UserEntity.class);
       
Criteria criteria1 = Criteria.where(isSaved).is(false);
Criteria criteria2 = Criteria.where(boughtDate).lte(Utility.Today);

Query query = new Query(criteria1.andOperator(criteria2));

        
Update update = new Update();
update.set(isPromoValid, true);
            
bulkOps.updateMulti(query, update);
BulkWriteResult result = bulkOps.execute();
```